# How to iterate over array of hashes and hash with smallest attribute

Tags: ruby

I've got an array of hashes and I need to figure out which hash has the smallest height attributes.  So given this array,

```
[{"height"=>130, "source"=>"http.facebook.com/tiny_pic.jpg", "width"=>173},    
 {"height"=>1230, "source"=>"http.facebook.com/giant_pic.jpg", "width"=>1273}]
```

I want to return this

```
{"height"=>130, "source"=>"http.facebook.com/tiny_pic.jpg", "width"=>173}
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's just an array so:

```
array_of_hashes.min_by {|h| h['height']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`min`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) method:

```
hash = array.min { |a,b| a['height'] <=> b['height'] }
```